# PuTTY hang when issue some command

Tags: putty

Issue happen for AWS instance. When I tried to trigger `ps -ef`, `ls -rtlh` a folder with a lot files, and issue a `top` command, the PuTTY session when hang on the session did not provide any output, I am also not able to quit with CTRL + C or CTRL + Z.

This issues only occur in PuTTY, when I tried to use others terminal such as mobaXterm, is working fine.

I had also tried `putty.exe -cleanup`, after cleanup the issues still persist.

I had enabled the log, it given output below:

```
=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~= PuTTY log 2019.10.02 09:16:27 =~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=
login as: xxx    
Authenticating with public key "xxx"
Last login: Wed Oct  2 09:11:29 2019 from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

 ]0;xxx:~  [?1034h[xxx ~]$ cd   [K  [K  [Kps -ef
```

Cloud anyone help to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Em.. it just like normal login and type the command in terminal, then it went hang.

Comment: Hi, issue has been resolve, that is due to network issue. To connect to AWS VPN, the MTU must set less that 1500 due to it not able to support Jumbo frame.

Answer (score 2):

issue has been resolve, that is due to network issue. To connect to AWS VPN, the MTU must set less that 1500 due to it not able to support Jumbo frame.